# Split a column value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a column based on whether a slash('/) is present in the cell within that column. Not all cells contain slashes. Most only contain 3 letters (e.g.'ABC').

I am trying to avoid for loops since they affect performance. I have tried the following code:

```
df.column.split('/',expand=True)
```

I get the following outut:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You need `str` accessor after the column name. Check `df.column.str.split('/',expand=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:

```
df.column.str.split('/',expand=True)
```